# How can I add content in between views in bootstrap grid format?

Tags: views, theming, bootstrap-theme

How can I add content in between views in grid format?

Header and footer is fine, but how about interrupting the flow of grids, is there a module for that?

Or do I need to hard code a template file?

Or maybe use css to make the element full width at X item number in the grid?

Image to explain here:

[image]

Comment: Please be aware that we do not provide tutorials or step-by-step instructions for achieving functionality from a description, screenshot or other website, as explained in the [help center](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Instead explain your attempt(s), and be as complete as possible. All the ideas you have come up with could work. What kind of answer would you hope to get?

Comment: Got my answer from Apoch800

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am stepping in with the response of Neograph734. Google is your friend and you can easily find the answers there.

But I am going to help you. It is easy to be done:
Create a view (page or block) and setup the filter and order criteria to what you want to display. In the pager section, set items to display to 3.

Make an attachment display with the same filter and order criteria. attach the attachment to the first view. Take "attach after" . Then in the pager section, determine how many items you want to show and set the offset to 3.

This way you can either put in the footer section of the first view or the header section of the attachment the text you want to place there.

Comment: Brilliant solution that works 100%. Problem about searching on Google is often that people don't know what to search for. It's the "you don't know what you don't know" paradox , so thanks for pointing me in the right direction despite of Stackexchange's draconian rules...your answer opened a whole new world of display options for me ;)

Comment: @BrunoVincent, recently there are a lot of new posts here of people that have not used Google and just post "I need X". I (personally) drop a similar note as above to motivate people to include their own research and attempts in the question. If people expect me to do their work, I expect payment; if people are stuck with a problem, I want to help. I know this is a thin line and perhaps more personal than an SE rule. But I also hope it will encourage people to write high quality questions with visible research effort. Glad to see your problem is solved :)